# shell script : how to validate function is returning 1 text line?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I try to generate a csv file through a lot of functions like that :

```
function get_sudo_version {
  sudo -V 2>/dev/null|grep -i "sudo version"
}
sudo_version=$(get_sudo_version)
```

Function above is a simple example but in some cases  i cannot be sure the output is correct.
I would like to know what is the best way to validate the function return one text line only.

I thought about something like that

```
function validate_output {  
  output=$1; 
  echo $1|grep -q "\n"; 
  echo $?; 
}

mytest="val1
err2
err3"
```

But it's obviously not working because the variable does not keep the retrun line character:

```
echo $mytest
val1 err2 err3
```

So if someone has a good idea of how i could wirte a generic check function i would be glad.

Thanks

Comment: Always quote your expansions. `echo "$mytest"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU grep, you *could* simply ensure that grep doesn't produce more than one line of output in the first place via `grep -m 1`. Alternatively, use `sed '/sudo version/!d;q'` instead of `grep`.

A function that simply checks lines of input while passing them through might look like:

```
shopt -s lastpipe # if bash

# ksh or bash
validate_output() { 
    (( $(tee >(wc -l) >&2) == 1 ))
} 2>&1

# bash
validate_output2() {
    local lines
    tee /dev/fd/2 | mapfile -tc1 -C '((++lines < 2)) || return; :'
    ((lines))
} 2>&1

get_sudo_version | validate_output || echo failed
```

Many variations on that possible of course. IMO it's pretty pointless and shouldn't be used for something like this. Just design your `get_sudo_version` so that it guarantees the right results.

Comment: thanks. you are right, for sudo version alone it's pointless but i will have a lot of functions some provided by other people so having a standard way to validate output seem a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can count lines with `wc -l`:

```
$ LINES="$(echo -n | wc -l)"; [[ "$LINES" -gt 0 ]] && echo 'at least one line'

$ LINES="$(echo -e 'a\nb\nc' | wc -l)"; [[ "$LINES" -gt 0 ]] && echo 'at least one line'
at least one line
```

Comment: thanks but if i do that i will need to run each command 2 times. i would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @AlainDejoux I really see no reason why you would need to run each command twice. I guess you are missing something simple.